# how to navigate from one component to another component without carrying any parameters(id) in angularjs2?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my appcomponent it consists of two button login and signup which directs to corresponding components.
In my signupcomponent when the user enters all the text field and clicks the submit button all the text field should disappear and content in my confcomponent show be displayed.(I want to navigate from signupcomponent to confcomponent)

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="ui buttons">
      <button class="ui button"routerLink="/login"routerLinkActive="active">Login</button>
      <div class="or"></div>
      <button routerLink="/signUp"routerLinkActive="active">SignUp</button>
    </div>   
    <div class="ui form margin-top">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { signUpComponent }    from './signUp.component';
import { loginComponent }    from './login.component';
import { confComponent }    from './conf.component';
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'signUp', component: signUpComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: loginComponent },
  { path: 'conf', component: confComponent }
];
export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

signup.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: `
    <h5 class="ui header">Admin detail</h5>
    <form>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Admin Name">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Admin's Email-id">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Admin's Password">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
      </div>
      <div class="ui warning message">
        <div class="header">Authentication failed!</div>
        <p>Please check your Email-id and Password</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui animated button" tabindex="0">
        <div class="visible content" routerLink="/conf" routerLinkActive="active">
          Submit and Proceed
        </div>
        <div class="hidden content">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class signUpComponent { }
```

Comment: Till now i came across snippets which navigates from fixed menus to some component. I need something like "back button" which we found on angularjs2 documentation example but it should lead to another component not to the previous one.

Comment: I have included the images, but you are probably going to get better help if you include your code as (code formatted) text in the question rather than in screenshots.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I have included my code for your reference.

Comment: Appreciated, unfortunately I am not the correct person to help you with this, I just hope you will get better response from others.

Comment: yeah got it man, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
 this.router.navigate(['/router']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigate by URl

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

this.parentRouter = Router
this.parentRouter.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

Navigate by Component

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

http://playcode.org/routing-in-angular-2-rc-1/ look at this url in detail hope this helps you

Comment: Yes thanks man, It helps me but the thing is the files are not correctly imported. So to use "this.route.navigate();" what are the files to be imported and if there exists any stable version for routing include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set them to `null` explicitely. In the latest router version (RC.1) it should be the default that query parameters and fragment are not passed along when a routerLink is clicked or `router.navigate(...)` is called.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9786
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/CHANGELOG.md#300-rc1-2016-08-09

Answer (score 0):

Just use this. Declare `ProdutsList` in `app.routing.module` file

```
this.router.navigate(['/ProdutsList'])
```

add `router` in constructor like this `private router: Router`